Repeated MySQL Select statement based on integer in a record
I have a table that looks something like the following.



letter
count




A
5


B
3



How can I do a SELECT in MySQL that would produce something like the following output?



column1
column2




A
1


A
2


A
3


A
4


A
5


B
1


B
2


B
3



I have not tried anything just yet because I am pretty new at MySQL and didn't have a great idea where to start.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here's one possible solution:
create table mytable (
  letter char(1),
  count int
);

insert into mytable values ('A', 5), ('B', 3);

select t.letter, n.n
from mytable as t
join (values row (1), row (2), row (3), row (4), row (5)) as n(n)
  on t.count >= n.n
order by t.letter, n.n;

Result, tested in MySQL 8.0.39:
+--------+---+
| letter | n |
+--------+---+
| A      | 1 |
| A      | 2 |
| A      | 3 |
| A      | 4 |
| A      | 5 |
| B      | 1 |
| B      | 2 |
| B      | 3 |
+--------+---+

The number of rows in n should be at least as much as the largest count you have in the table.
If you can't predict the largest count, or if this solution seems beyond your current skill level in SQL, you should consider if it would be easier to solve in some other programming language.

Thank you, Bill. I think this may help me. Since I'm a bit new at MySQL, I will have to play with it a little. Have a great day!
